# 18.04 Cannot manage workspaces

Tags: workspaces

I have a laptop with an extra screen attached (one which is shareable with my Mac via a little switch).  Recently when I had had both screens attached to the laptop, I disconnected the external screen, leaving a couple of windows on there.  I had extreme trouble moving these windows to the laptop screen, both in that same session and for some time later.

I decided to look into workspaces, and right clicked on the icon, whereupon the following message came up:

There was an error loading the preferences dialogue for Workspacebar:

Error: Requiring St, version none: Typelib file for namespace 'Clutter', version '2' not found

Stack trace:
  @/home/james/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspace-bar@markbokil.com/prefs.js:6:7
  _getExtensionPrefsModule@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:75:13
  wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
  _selectExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:90:31
  wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
  _onCommandLine@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:243:17
  wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
  main@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:397:5
  @:1:43

Can someone tell me what this means, and even more important, what I need to do about it.  Is there a description that will tell me how to use workspaces?  It's a fair while since I last used them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/mbokil/workspacebar/issues/2), comment out line 6 in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspace-bar@markbokil.com/prefs.js`. Tested & works.